# javascript select2 allowed tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to allow users select ONLY allowed tags in select.

Currently I have that:

```
$("input#id_txtcolor").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
```

Can you help me please with that?

Comment: from the documentation: "Note that when tagging is enabled the user can select from pre-existing tags or create a new tag by picking the first choice which is what the user has typed into the search box so far." So i guess you might be out of luck... but have you tried setting `maximumInputLength` to 0, that might prevent the user from entering new tags?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

as of 3.3 you can specify your own createSearchChoice when using tags that will always return null, thus preventing the default choice from being created.

```
$().select2({
    createSearchChoice: function() { return null; },
    tags:...
});
```

Comment: @reverbnation answer is better, this technically works but is more of a hack, then using the correct behaviour

Comment: @Stefan, yep, there's no reason to do it this way when you can just make it a multiple select input.

Comment: This is a better aproach to disable user custom tags if you are using Yii Framework - Yiiwheels -  WhSelect2. As you are prefilling the 'data' property.
Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes we developer don't use our 7th sense that is common sense also happened with me struggled for 2 hours then it clicked my sense..
if you want user to select only allowed values then its no more **tagging** its **selecting** So just remove `tags:true` option and keep `mulitple` attribute in select, provide options directly in select element or load remote data.